# Comma rather than dot in number format when using FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, format, numbers

I am trying to run a macro on a German-"based" Excel.

This means, the value of cell H3 is 0,8 (which is 0.8 in the US).

Let I4 be occupied with an integer.

I get a runtime error at the formula due to the comma-separator:

```
Sub test()

Dim numb as Double

numb = Range("H3").Value * 23   ' numb = 18,4 and I cannot change it to 18.4

Range("H4").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] < numb, ""ok"", ""not ok"")"

End Sub
```

I am aware that the comma is causing the problem. VBA requires 18.4 and not 18,4.

Is there any way to fix this within VBA, that is, without changing the language settings of Excel?

I tried using number as a string, I replaced the comma with a dot etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it is not any connection between the 'comma' and your problem. Excel knows how to deal with decimal separator...

Try this way, please:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] < " & numb & ", ""ok"", ""not ok"")"
```

Excel does not recognize `numb` in the way you used it. It must be separated by the rest of the string.

If you really need the change the decimal separator, for something connected to some strings to be processed, or you want to check your theory, you can do it on the fly:

```
Private Sub ChangeSep()     
 Application.DecimalSeparator = "."            

  'do here what you want testing
  'for instance: ActiveCell.value = CStr(1,00000001)

 Application .DecimalSeparator = ","
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to put the correct version up there. But this concetanation does not work either...

Comment: @alex: What do you mean? What value does `numb` return?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] < " & numb & ", ""ok"", ""not ok"")"   returns a runtime error because numb = 18,4. However, the formula requires it to be 18.4

Comment: I have a "cheap" solution now: I am storing the result of Range("H3").Value * 23 in a Worksheet cell now and refer to this cell in the VBA code. Then, VBA knows how to treat the number correctly.

Comment: @alex:  Try please, inserting the next line after `numb = Range("H3").Value * 23` and show us how the `dumb` value is shown in Imediate Window: `Debug.Print numb: Stop`

Comment: @alex:  your "cheap" solution looks the same for me. We must understand what is the really wrong thing happening... So. what `Debug.Print numb` does return?

Comment: @alex: I changed the decimal separator (in comma) in my installation and the formula works without any problem... I suppose that you know that `RC[-1]` means "G4" for active cell being `Range("H4")`. What do you have at "G4"? VBA read `dumb` as `18.4`. I copied it from Imediate window. But uses it in the formula in the way to respect your decimal separator settings.

Comment: Thank you. Debug.Print returns 18,4

Concerning your last comment: This is a helpful advice, thanks .-)
At G4, I have any number, e.g. 2

You helped me solving the question, thank you!

Comment: @alex: Glad I could help you!

Comment: @alex: But, when an answer code solved your problem, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it accepted answer. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar problem, will know that this was a solution... :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I posted the answer (but can only check it in 2 days :-D)

Comment: @alex: No problem with me! Even if you will not check it like accepted answer. I also updated my answer showing a method to change the decimal separator on the fly, do whatever you need or you want checking and changing it back at the end... Not for this specific question, just in case, if you will also have such existential questions about wrong functioning of your code reason...

Comment: @alex: I checked my answered questions and I can see the code and the check box in discussion even using my mobile phone...

Answer (score 1):

Answer by FaneDuru:
@alex: I changed the decimal separator (in comma) in my installation and the formula works without any problem...

"Cheap" Solution:
Store the result of Range("H3").Value * 23 in a Worksheet cell and refer to this cell in the VBA code. Then, VBA knows how to treat the number correctly.